# Find the number of elements of a complex subset

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How many elements does the set $\{z\in \mathbb C:z^{60}=-1,z^k\not=-1\text{ for } 0<k<60\}$ have ?
>
> (A) $24$   (B) $30$   (C) $32$   (D) $45$. Which is correct ?

$z^{60}=-1=\cos(2k\pi+\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi+\pi)$. Then , $z=\cos\left(\frac{2k+1}{60}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k+1}{60}\pi\right)$ , for $k=0,1,\ldots,59$. But I am unable to use the second condition.

Please anyone  help me.......

Comment: I think this question already have been discused some days ago

Comment: @ –  Chiranjeev  ) then please give the link...

Comment: I saw this question  here some months ago. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @  Michael Hardy) then please give the link...Your ' here ' does not contain any link

Comment: I was searching this but unable to find that.. Sorry

Comment: @  Chiranjeev ) Then can you discuss it further ?

Comment: @ Michael Hardy) then please give the link...Your ' here ' does not contain any link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** How much integers from $ \ 1 \ $ to $ \ 119 \ $ are relatively prime to $ \ 60 \ $ ?

Your sixty complex roots of $ \ -1 \ $ are $ \ cis(3º) \ , \ cis(9º) \ , \ cis(15º) \ , \ \ldots \ , \ cis(357º) \ $ . Consider which ones will give you $ \ cis(180º) \ $ if you raise them to any power *other than* $ \ 60 \ $ (you want to discard *those*), and which ones can't.

**EDIT (9/5) :** I was just not seeing that I had stopped with the first thirty roots.  I have corrected the upper end of the range from $ \ 59 \ $ to $ \ 119 \ $.

Comment: I found that the number of integers from $1$ to $59$ are relatively prime to $60$ is 16...which differs from the answer ...I am unable to understand your 2nd argument..

Comment: Is $ \ k = 0 \ $ to be included or not?  The question says no, but your listing says yes.  The first root that satisfies the second condition $ \ z^k \ \neq \ -1 \ $ is $ \ cis \ \frac{\pi}{60} \ $ .  The others, $ \ cis \ \frac{m \ \pi}{60} \ $ that work are integer $ \ m \ $ being any prime $ \ 7 \ \le \ m \ \le \ 59 \ $ and $ \ m = 49 \ $ .  In my second statement, I am saying that the second condition means we don't want any power other than 60 to give -1 . So $ \  ( e^{\frac{3 \pi}{60}})^{20} \ = \ -1 \ $ requires us to reject that root,  (continued)

Comment: but   $ \  ( e^{\frac{7 \pi}{60}})^{k} \ = \ -1 \ $ is only true for $ \ k = 60 \ $ and no lower positive integer.  I count 16 roots if we include $ \ cis \ \frac{\pi}{60} \ $ and 15 if we don't.  (Also, your use of $ \ k \ $ differs from that in the question.)

Comment: Integers from  $1$ to $59$ which are relatively prime are : $1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,49,53,59$.....In my list excluding $0$ there are $16$ integers .....

Comment: Please see my updated answer...There are four options ...

Comment: What is the source of this question?  I've read it a number of times and it seems like it is asking for the "primitive roots" of $ \ -1 \ $ , but the size of the choices makes me think the poser _meant_ to ask about the complement of that set.

Comment: It is a question of a competitive exam. Yes..Number of Primitive n-th roots of $1$  is $\phi(n)$...But is it same for $-1$ ? I think NOT.

Comment: I think I realized what the issue is:  I'm not going _high enough_.  (I've only been going through thirty of the roots. I should have been counting up to $ \ e^{\frac{119 \ \pi}{60}} \ $ . )  We need the numbers from 1 to **119** that are relatively prime to 60.   So that's 1, all the primes through 113, and the composite integers which do not have factors of 2, 3, or 5 . (The composites are 49, 77, 91, and 119.)  _Now_ I count 32.  [Sorry about that -- I was just _not_ seeing that I stopped too soon.]

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368003/number-of-60th-primitive-roots-of-1

Comment: I had tried a search on primitive roots early on, but hadn't turned up _that_ page.  (Unfortunately, as this site continues to expand, it is becoming more difficult to hunt for duplications that are well-answered.)  This same question has come up at least once again in the past week or so.