# How many elements does the following set have?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid z^{60}=-1, z^k \not=-1 \text{ for } 0<k<60\}$ I tried to solve this but I've no idea on this type of questions, how to get start or in which way should I proceed. How can i do this?

Comment: Open   this  link  :  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368003/number-of-60th-primitive-roots-of-1   It  has  this   question  as  well  as  answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That are just the primitive 120th roots, so we are looking for
$$\varphi(120)=\varphi(8)\cdot\varphi(3)\cdot\varphi(5)=4\cdot 2\cdot 4=32.$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** First prove:
\begin{align*}
z^{60} = -1 \text{ and } z^k \ne -1 \text{ for } 0 < k < 60
&\iff z^{120} = 1 \text{ and } z^k \ne 1 \text{ for } 0 < k < 120.
\end{align*}
Then note that
$$
\{z^{120} = 1 \text{ and } z^k \ne 1 \text{ for } 0 < k < 120\}
$$
is the set of primitive $120$th roots of unity.